# How to show language specific syntax highlighted code inside activity in an android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, editor

I want to show java as well as xml code with `syntax` highlighting inside Activity. But I don't know how to do so .Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this library out here:

https://github.com/kbiakov/CodeView-Android

Answer (score 1):

You can use CodeView Library to create syntax highlighter and auto-complete easily,

you need to define your syntax with pattern and set color for each group for example

```java
codeview.addSyntaxPattern(Pattern.compile("#[a-zA-z0-9]+"), Color.BLUE);
```

You can use add, remote, clear Syntax Pattern to change the rules in the runtime or change the theme colors, you can also define keywords for auto-complete with custom layout,

Check the full documentation for more information

https://github.com/AmrDeveloper/CodeView